# Eclipse 2022-03 RCP App Create p2 Repository fails with "invoking the director"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to export an app with the p2 repository created. Without the p2 everything is working fine (exporting and starting the exported app).

Eclipse shows me the following error:

```
E:\Eclipse-Workspace-RCP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:90: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Eclipse-Workspace-RCP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:1410: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Fabia\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.11.100.v20210916-0743\scripts\genericTargets.xml:241: A problem occured while invoking the director.
The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Eclipse-Workspace-RCP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:1410: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Fabia\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.11.100.v20210916-0743\scripts\genericTargets.xml:241: A problem occured while invoking the director.
```

To dig deeper into the problem, I created the following entry into the `genericTargets.xml`:

```
<record name="e:\eclipse-build.log" loglevel="verbose"></record>
```

The log file contains the following errors:

```
Override ignored for property "p2.director.version"
Property "p2.director.log" has not been set
[p2.director] Installing 1.7.4 1.7.4.
[p2.director] Installation failed.
[p2.director] Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
[p2.director]   Software being installed: Software-Name 1.7.4 (1.7.4 1.7.4)
[p2.director]   Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: Software-Name 1.7.4 (1.7.4 1.7.4) requires 'osgi.ee; JavaSE [17.0.0,17.0.0]' but it could not be found
[p2.director] Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
[p2.director] Software being installed: Software-Name 1.7.4 (1.7.4 1.7.4)
[p2.director] Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: Software-Name 1.7.4 (1.7.4 1.7.4) requires 'osgi.ee; JavaSE [17.0.0,17.0.0]' but it could not be found
A problem occured while invoking the director.
runDirector:  duration 0 seconds
```

I think this is way more specific, but I have no clue how to fix this. Where is JavaSE in Version 17.0.0 missing? I have different versions on my machine installed:

```
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.2+8 (build 17.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.2+8 (build 17.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Is this already the problem, because Java 17.0.0 is needed specifically?

--- First Edit ---

I tried changing the Java requirements "here and there" because I am not quite sure which setting is doing what.
The workspace default is `org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.2.v20220201-1208` and this is set for the Eclipse RCP project. The requirements are set to `Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17` and this seems to be a problem already? The UI says it is the minimum requirement, but this does not seem to be true.

At the moment I have no idea how to match these versions. In the best case, a lower Java version is required and I am including Java 17 or 15 in the bundle. Does this make any sense? :)

--- Second Edit ---

Here is my `.product` file. There is no `p2.inf/*.p2.inf` files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="MyProduct" uid="1.7.4" id="MyProduct.product" application="MyProduct.application" version="1.7.4" useFeatures="false" includeLaunchers="true">


   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-clearPersistedState
      </programArgs>
      <programArgsWin>-data @user.home/temp/workspace -nl en -configuration c:/temp/eclipse
      </programArgsWin>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages i16="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-16x16.gif" i32="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-32x32.gif" i48="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-48x48.gif" i64="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-64x64.gif" i128="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-128x128.gif" i256="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-256x256.gif"/>

   <splash
      location="MyProduct"
      startupProgressRect="5,270,518,15"
      startupMessageRect="5,250,518,20"
      startupForegroundColor="FFFFFF" />
   <launcher name="MyProduct">
      <win useIco="true">
         <ico path="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-multi-size.ico"/>
         <bmp
            winSmallHigh="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-icon-16x16-32bit.bmp"
            winSmallLow="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-icon-16x16-8bit.bmp"
            winMediumHigh="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-icon-32x32-32bit.bmp"
            winMediumLow="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-icon-32x32-8bit.bmp"
            winLargeHigh="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-icon-48x48-32bit.bmp"
            winLargeLow="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-icon-48x48-8bit.bmp"
            winExtraLargeHigh="/MyProduct/icons/MyProduct-icon-256x256-32bit.bmp"/>
      </win>
   </launcher>


   <vm>
      <windows include="true">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-17</windows>
   </vm>

   <plugins>
      <plugin id="MyProduct"/>
      <plugin id="biz.aQute.bnd.util"/>
      <plugin id="biz.aQute.bndlib"/>
      <plugin id="ch.qos.logback.classic"/>
      <plugin id="ch.qos.logback.core"/>
      <plugin id="ch.qos.logback.slf4j" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="com.google.guava"/>
      <plugin id="com.ibm.icu"/>
      <plugin id="com.jcraft.jsch"/>
      <plugin id="com.sun.jna" version="5.8.0.v20210503-0343"/>
      <plugin id="com.sun.jna.platform" version="5.8.0.v20210406-1004"/>
      <plugin id="jakarta.servlet-api"/>
      <plugin id="javax.activation"/>
      <plugin id="javax.annotation"/>
      <plugin id="javax.el"/>
      <plugin id="javax.inject"/>
      <plugin id="javax.servlet.jsp"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.ant"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.constants"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.css"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.i18n"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.batik.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.codec"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.io"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.jxpath"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.gogo.command"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.gogo.shell"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.jasper.glassfish"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.log4j"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.lucene.analyzers-common"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.lucene.analyzers-smartcn"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.lucene.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.xerces"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.xml.resolver"/>
      <plugin id="org.apache.xmlgraphics"/>
      <plugin id="org.apiguardian"/>
      <plugin id="org.bouncycastle.bcpg"/>
      <plugin id="org.bouncycastle.bcprov"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.launching"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ant.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.compare"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.compare.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.contenttype"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding.property"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.expressions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.externaltools"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filebuffers"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.jobs"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.net"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.resources.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.variables"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.debug.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.debug.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions.supplier"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.tools"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.tools.compat"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.editor3x"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.tools.emf.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.tools.jdt.templates"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.tools.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.dialogs"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.dialogs.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.ide"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.ide.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.win32" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.swt.win32.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3.source"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.common.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.databinding.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.app"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.bidi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.directorywatcher"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extensionlocation"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.jarprocessor"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.registry"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.help"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.help.base"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.help.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.help.webapp"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.annotation"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.debug"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.launching"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jem.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.http"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.io"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.security"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.server"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ajax"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jetty.xml"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.databinding"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.notifications"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.jface.text"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.m2e.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.m2e.workspace.cli"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.services"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi.util"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.pde"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.pde.build"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.pde.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.pde.launching"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.pde.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.rap.tools.launch.rwt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.rcp"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.search"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.team.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.team.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.text"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.console"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.editors"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.forms"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.ide"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.intro"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.views"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.views.log"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.win32" fragment="true"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.urischeme"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.emf"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.environment"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.sse.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.validation"/>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.wst.xml.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.hamcrest.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.junit"/>
      <plugin id="org.junit.platform.commons"/>
      <plugin id="org.junit.platform.engine"/>
      <plugin id="org.junit.platform.launcher"/>
      <plugin id="org.opentest4j"/>
      <plugin id="org.sat4j.core"/>
      <plugin id="org.sat4j.pb"/>
      <plugin id="org.slf4j.api"/>
      <plugin id="org.tukaani.xz"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.css.sac"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.events"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.smil"/>
      <plugin id="org.w3c.dom.svg"/>
   </plugins>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>

   <preferencesInfo>
      <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
   </preferencesInfo>

   <cssInfo>
   </cssInfo>

</product>
```

Comment: What is "Software-Name 1.7.4"? A plugin? A feature? It appears to be requiring exactly 17.0.0 (so 17.0.2 is not acceptable)

Comment: What greg-449 says. The Eclipse platform requires only Java 11 or higher. Consider embedding the right Java into your Eclipse RCP application (e.g. as plugin via [Eclipse JustJ](https://www.eclipse.org/justj/)).

Comment: "Software-Name 1.7.4" is my app. I changed it due to data privacy concerns. And I checked the JRE I included with my RCP app. It is the workspace default JRE 17.0.2, which is the original problem if I am not mistaken? I try to include the JustJ version and test if this changes anything.

Comment: I edited my question. At the moment I am not sure which Java version setting is doing what.

Comment: If you mean by _"app"_ your product (not a feature or a plugin), show your product definition file and the *.p2.inf file if it exists.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. My product was meant. I cannot find a *.p2.inf file. What do you mean by the product definition file? Which is the correct one?

Comment: Please show your `*.product` file and `p2.inf`/`*.p2.inf` files if you have any. Is your Eclipse up to date?

Comment: I added my ```.product``` file. I changed the product Name to "MyProduct", but everything else is the same as the original file. There are no ```p2.inf / *.p2.inf``` files. I am using Eclipse for RCP and RAP 2022-03.

Comment: That's a product based on plugins instead of features and I guess, Java will be included via the `jre` subfolder into the product, right? Consider to migrate to a product based on features and using Tycho for building (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized)) which would make maintenance much simpler and also [including Java as a feature](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/packages/org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product/epp.product?id=cf6cb27a6b5ca380232cc9bd630d4ea39af67aec#n214). Do you get the same issue without `<vm>...</vm>`?

Comment: Without the ```<vm>...</vm>``` entry everything is working fine. That's odd because I thought I checked this. Now I have two questions: Is the purpose of the p2 directory only to provide an update mechanism? This is not necessary at the moment for the product. And isn't it the better solution to integrate the ```jre``` into the product? I thought this would remove the necessity to install Java on the target machine? But maybe I am completely mistaken? And the plugins to features switch is contemplated for Q4 this year. Unfortunately this is no option at this time.

Comment: Yes, p2 is an update mechanism, but it also simplifies building with Maven and Tycho. Beside the old way of including Java via the `jre` folder, [Eclipse JustJ](https://www.eclipse.org/justj/) offers p2 update sites to include Java as a feature and `-vm` is added to the ini file by p2. Using a product that is based on features instead of on plugins is easier to maintain because a feature is more stable (you don't have to adapt anything when a plugin is added). And p2 speeds up startup time of your app. Looking back, I would have saved myself time if I had switched to p2 and Tycho earlier.

Comment: Without the `<vm>...</vm>` entry, does manually creating a `jre` folder in the exported product and then copying a Java installation into this folder work (so that there will be `jre/bin/java.exe`)?